# Why I get more columns than expected after OneHotEncoding in a Sklearn Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, one-hot-encoding

I'm using sklearn pipelines to preprocess my data.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('imputer', KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2,weights='uniform', metric='nan_euclidean', add_indicator=True))
   ])
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[ 
    ('one_hot_encoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore'))])


from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector as selector

numeric_features = ['Latitud','Longitud','Habitaciones','Dormitorios','Baños','Superficie_Total','Superficie_cubierta']
categorical_features = ['Tipo_de_propiedad']
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
   transformers=[
    ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numeric_features, selector(dtype_exclude="category"))
   ,('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical_features, selector(dtype_include="category"))])
```

The feature `Tipo_de_propiedad` has 3 classes: 'Departamento', 'Casa', 'PH'.  So the 7 other features plus these dummies should give me 10 after transforming, but when I apply `fit_transform`, it returns 14 features.

```
train_transfor=pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train))
train_transfor.head()
```

[image: output]

When I use `pd.get_dummies` it works well, but I can't use that to apply in the `Pipeline`; `OneHotEncoder` is useful because I can fit on train set and transform on the test set.

```
dummy=pd.get_dummies(df30[["Tipo_de_propiedad"]])
df_new=pd.concat([df30,dummy],axis=1)
df_new.head()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `KNNImputer` has used the parameter `add_indicator=True`, so the additional columns are presumably missingness indicators for some of your numeric columns.

Comment: Ben, many thanks, do you know how can I see the original name of the columns?. As you saw in the picture, after pre-processing the name of the columns is changed to numbers.

Comment: `ColumnTransformer` and `OneHotEncoder` have the method `get_feature_names`, but `Pipeline` and `KNNImputer` and `StandardScaler` do not.  There is currently work going on to make this functionality more complete, but for now you would need to do it fairly manually.  It's a relatively separate question though; if you ask a new question, I (or someone else) can probably provide the manual method.